# What is the sample space of a stock price

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let X be the price of some stock at some date in the future. Then X is a random variable. The definition of a random variable, is a function $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)\rightarrow (E,\mathcal{E})$. I figured out that $E=\mathbb R_{\geq0}$, $\mathcal{E}$ is the Borel sigma algebra, $\mathcal{A}$ is the pullback of $\mathcal{E}$ under X and $P$ is the pullback of Lebesgue measure under X. However, I don’t know what the sample space $\Omega$ is in this case. If there are more options for $\Omega$, what is an option which is commonly used?

Comment: Sample space is simply all possible stock prices - non-negative reals.

Comment: My personal experience has been it's the set of all numbers smaller than, and tending to decrease from, the original purchase price!

Comment: There are many options for $\Omega$, and it is not generally too important which one you pick.  If $\Omega$ needs to be specified, common choices include $[0,1]$, $[0,\infty)$, and $\mathbb{R}$ for a single random variable, and the space of continuous functions $C([0,\infty))$ for random processes.